# JQuery in head section not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a value on the browser without refreshing the main page itself. However, it is not working. I am using JQuery, PHP and HTML.

Here is the HTML Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Live Update</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  $(document).ready(function(){    
     loadrandom();
  });

function loadrandom(){
    $("#random_data").load("random.php");
    setTimeout(loadrandom, 2000);
}
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="random_data"></div>
</body>   
</html>
```

Here is the random.php:

```
<?php
echo mt_rand(0,100);
?>
```

If I execute random.php, it works and echoes back a random number.

So, what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Where is jQuery included?

Comment: There is no jQuery include, hard to use jQuery when you do not load the library..... FYI: GET requests cache...

Comment: Where is the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

Comment: Hello,

I just try your script, if you don't forget to include jQuery, it perfectly works.

Comment: Where is the jQuery lib included?

Comment: Thanks... it works. In case you don't know. I am kind of new to JQuery. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code above your jquery script under the title tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```